# How to pass changed Array data from Target to Host element in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, dataflow

I have an array in host element which is passed to target element using binding. Now, I would like to change the array data in my target element making sure that the array data in my host element is also updated when I make changes to array in target element.

Comment: If still have problem from below, pls add your codes to able to go over it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the steps you need to check :

1. At child element (in your term : target) , you need to declare property with `notify:true`

   `static get properties() {return {
        myArray: { type:Array, notify:true }}}`
2. Allow two-way binding at the parent (your word: host) with `curly brackets` something like:`<child-elem my-array="{{myArray}}"></child-elem>`
3. At the child element, you need to modify array with some of below in order to observable changes at parent; 
   `this.push(path, item1, [..., itemN])
   this.pop(path)
   this.unshift(path, item1, [..., itemN])
   this.shift(path)
   this.splice(path, index, removeCount, [item1, ..., itemN])`

Comment: Good answer. A couple of things:
`static get properties()` (properties in plural) and `my-array="{{myArray}}"` (quotes around the curly braces). Also, it's a good practice to declare the array's value with a function to ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value: `static get properties() {return {myArray: { type: Array, value: () => [], notify: true }}}`